# Post method not working in webservices

Tags: php, web-services, post, get

I'm running a simple file just to test methods are working properly in webservices. while running the file with Get method it is working fine but Postmethod is not working . Below is my code

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST"){

 $abc=$_POST['name'];

   echo $abc;
}
else{
    echo "method not accepted";
}

header('Content-type:application/json');
?>
```

while running the code it automatically goes to else part .How can i get this resolve .If anybody can suggest will be appreciated.

Comment: what does `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` actually return?

Comment: I just want to check if the Post method working fine or not. I'm running the code through postman using Post but it directly goes to else part while in get method it works

Comment: no, just echo it

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly.
I believe, you are not making a POST request.
Suggestion:
If you are making the call from a form add

method="POST" in form tag

If you are making an ajax call
$.ajax({
url:"url",
type:"POST",
data:"data"
}).done();

Tip:
You can't make a post call,by simply hitting the url from browser. You have to use POSTMAN to make POST calls manually.

Comment: Have you changed the Call type from GET to POST? in POST MAN... Cuz it's by default GET there. Just check the box at the left.. of the place where you enter the url.

Comment: yes also done that, but its not working in post method

Comment: Can you send me the both full code? I will send you back the solution. prasantabose1310@gmail.com

Comment: code is mention in above. This is the simple code that i want to run through postman just to start webservice. But this simple code not working in server while it is running properly on localhost.

Comment: <?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST"){


   echo 123;
}
else{
    echo "method not accepted";
}

header('Content-type:application/json');
?>
Try this one once.

Comment: thanks for reply,but nothing has chnaged same thing happening ,it goes to else part directly

Comment: Well we tried, I guess you are making some minor mistake. It's running perfectly on my machine.  Well, what url are you hitting? localhost/filename.php or localhost/filename.php?name=myName

Comment: we are hitting correct url as per the methods like for post localhost/filename.php and for get  localhost/filename.php?name=myName

But it is working on localhost but not in server

Answer (score -1):

You should never use `==` to compare strings. Use `===` or `strcmp` to compare 2 strings.

Comment: we are not trying to compare string ,this is post and get method that we are using